# ImageView with same size of View(full screen) - Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, imageview

How to do programmatically ImageView with same size of View  in a way that there is no difference between devices ?

Comment: use autolayout....NSLayoutConstraint class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UIImageView *imgV =[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
imgV.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"draw.png"];
[self.view addSubview:imgV];
```

suppose draw.png is x*x size then draw@2x = 2*(x*x), draw@x = 3*(x*x)
please supply image draw.png, draw@2x.png , draw@3x.png in resource

hope it help

Comment: I have a code and a viewcontroller in my storyboard receiving this code. But viewcontroller is blank. It just makes receive what is in the class. And this class is a viewcoontroller.

BUT I want to be able to change the size of the "view" through the storyboard without touching the code. I did not want to do this programmatically, but through the storyboard. How do I do that ?

Answer (score 0):

With code you can create a **UIImageView** with giving the frame of superview.

```
UIImageView* myImageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
[myImageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"yourImage.jpg"]];
[self.view addSubview:myImageView];
```

By **Autolayout** using storyboards we can do like this.

Drag an **UIImageView** to the view and provide these constraints and add.

[image]

Comment: I have a code and a viewcontroller in my storyboard receiving this code. But viewcontroller is blank. It just makes receive what is in the class. And this class is a viewcoontroller.

BUT I want to be able to change the size of the "view" through the storyboard without touching the code. I did not want to do this programmatically, but through the storyboard. How do I do that ?